# Too many open files NGINX

Tags: nginx

I've got an error on OS X:

```
2020/10/11 02:45:00 [alert] 38577#0: *10290 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico", host: "127.0.0.1:9000", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/"
```

Tried to modify ulimit, got worker_rlimit_nofile 10000, project has like 1500-1600 files, but does it matter and what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to apply updated ulimit - reboot. If you can't easily reboot(for example if this is a production server) try answers from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot) question.